# Cache static HTML pages with get variables

Tags: javascript, html, caching, iframe

I have a website with a lot of iframes like this:

```
<iframes src="expamle.com\page.html?var=blabla&id=42" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I have to change `var=blabla&id=42` for each iFrame. These parameters are used in the javascript of the iframe. Is there any way to cache(give hints to the browser) `page.html` (static) once for all variables ?

I have to use an iframe since I want to be able to update this code ( from another server) & to run it in another scope.

Comment: You want to change the variables in all the iframes at once?

Comment: Can you clarify - is `page.html` on the same domain as the parent page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - Anything changing the query string represents a seperate resource for the browser.

However, you may be able to achieve that effect if you can make some slight changes to page.html. If you write it this way:

```
<iframes src="expamle.com\page.html#var=blabla&id=42" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Note the use of the `#` character - that's the key there.

The query string becomes simply "page.html" and will cache that way. However, the Javascript of that page will have access to the variable `document.location.hash`, which will contain "`var=blabla&id=42`". It'll be written as a single string, but it shouldn't be difficult to parse. Some libraries even use that tag to pass parameters in semi-real-time to iframes for IE6 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only used in the javascript but is really only 1 page server side don't use ? But use # it will consider it as the same page but at diferent anchor pounts. So if test.com/#foo is cached then test.col/#bar is too (same page, different anchor points)

Answer (score -1):

You can update the frame URLs from code:

```
var fr = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
var sites = "1.com,2.com".split(",");

for(var x=0;x<fr.length;x++) {
     document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[x].src="http://"+sites[x];
}
```